# Poincare duality-differential geometry

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, duality

Let $ M $ be a smooth and compact manifold with boundary $\partial M = X \times F $ on which the structure of a smooth locally trivial bundle $$ \pi: \partial M \longrightarrow X $$
where the $ X $  and the fiber $ F $ are smooth compact manifolds without boundary. Consider the equivalence relation on the set M
\begin{equation}
z \sim z^{\prime} \Longleftrightarrow z = z^{\prime} \quad \text {or} \quad (z, z^ {\prime} \in \partial M \quad \text{and} \quad \pi(z) = \pi (z^{\prime})).
\end{equation}
We define the topological space $ N = M / \sim $ as the quotient space of the manifold M with respect to the equivalence relation above.
Informally speaking, $ N $ is obtained from $ M $ (by contracting the fibers of the bundle $ \pi $ to points). The set $ N $ is a disjoint union $ N = X \sqcup M^{\circ} $ of the manifold $ X $ and the interior  $ M^{\circ} $ of $ M $. The natural projection of $$ p: M \longrightarrow N $$ coincides with the identity map on $ M ^ {\circ} $ and the projection $ \pi $ on $ \partial M $.
So the manifold $N$ can be not smooth sometimes. The pair $(M,\pi)$ is called  a manifold with fibered boundared.
How to define the map $I : H^{n-k}_{dR}(M,\pi)\longrightarrow H_{k}(N)$ when $F$ is not a singleton?

Comment: How do you obtain $N$?

Comment: I reformuled my question. Compte on you help.

Comment: Dear Ryan, I hope it's clear how I define the problem.

Comment: Is the locally-trivial bundle $M$ or its boundary?  And you have not said what the map $I$ is supposed to be.  Is there a situation where your map has a name?

Comment: the boundary is the locally trivial bundle. I can want to define any in case where $F$ is not a singleton. Assume that is $F$ is a singleton, then projection pi is trivial and in that case $M=N$. I suppose now the case where $F$ is not a singleton. Then $N$ may be not smooth. I wanna define a map (any map) which holds when is not smooth.

Comment: In the first line of your question you say the boundary is a product.  This could be confusing.

Comment: You are right. I hope the question is clear now.

Comment: Hello, Dear Ryan! Any idea about the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Note that $N$ is  homeomorphic  to the union  of $M$ with $\DeclareMathOperator{\Cyl}{Cyl}$ the mapping cylinder $\Cyl(\pi)$ of the bundle projection $\newcommand{\pa}{\partial}$ $\pi:\pa M\to X$.  Denote by $M^\circ$ the interior of $M$.

Observe that the Poincare Duality  for $M^\circ$ (or equivalently for $(M,\pa M)$) implies 
$$
H^{n-k}_{dR}(M)\cong H^k_{dR}(M^\circ) \cong H^k_{cpt}(M^\circ).
$$
The extension by $0$ defines a morphism
$$
H^k_{cpt}(M^\circ)\to H^k_{cpt}(N)\cong H^k(N)\cong \mathrm{Hom}\big(H_k(N),\mathbb{R}\big).
$$
**Comment.** Above I assumed that $H^\bullet_{dR}(M,\pi)=H^\bullet_{dR}(M)$. Now observe that 
$$
H^{n-k}_{dR}(M)\cong H_k(M,\pa M).
$$
From the excision property of homology we deduce that the inclusion 
$$
(M,\pa M)\hookrightarrow (N,\Cyl \pi)
$$
induces an isomorphism
$$
H_k(M,\pa M)\cong H_k(N,\Cyl \pi).
$$
If $H_k(X)=H_{k-1}(X)=0$, then $H_k(N)\cong  H_k(N,\Cyl \pi)$.

Comment: Thanks Liviu. But how can I define exiplicitly the map $I$ when N is not smooth? In the case where $N$ is not smooth, how can I define a map $$I : H^{n-k}_{dR}(M, \pi)\longrightarrow H_{k}(N)$$

Comment: Since this comment is a bit longer I will add it to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Liviu. thanks very much.  So, could you define the map $I$ please. hint $\omega \in H^{n-k}_{dR}(M)$. How to sent $\omega$ to $ H_{k}(N)$. what is equal $I(\omega)$?

Comment: This map is not always well defined. The natural map is $$H^{n-k}_{dR}(M)\to H^k(N )\cong\text{Hom}\;\big(\; H_k(N),\mathbb{R}\;\big)$$